# How to merge elements and group them

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

How can I merge the following XML snippets:

**Snippet 1:**

```
    <drug>
        <title>Paracetamol</title>
        <indications outputclass="indicationsAndDose">
            <title>Indications and dose</title>
            <body>
                <section outputclass="indicationAndDoseGroup">
                    <sectiondiv outputclass="therapeuticIndications">
                        <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 1</p>
                        <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 2</p>
                    </sectiondiv>
                </section>
            </body>
        </indications>
    </drug>
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
    <drug>
        <title>Abacavir</title>
        <indications outputclass="indicationsAndDose">
            <title>Indications and dose</title>
            <body>
                <section outputclass="indicationAndDoseGroup">
                    <sectiondiv outputclass="therapeuticIndications">
                        <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 2</p>
                    </sectiondiv>
                </section>
            </body>
        </indications>
    </drug>
```

**Acceptance Criteria:**

I need to output an XML snippet that is a superset of Snippet 1 and Snippet 2 but it needs to be done in a distinct manner based on elements, attributes and values.

1. When elements are the same and the value is different and they have no attributes they should be merged e.g. "Paracetamol" and "Abacavir"
2. When the elements have the same attribute then they should be merged value e.g. "Some indication 1"
3. The solution should be dynamic in that the above rules could be applied to any type of element i.e. `<title>` `<section>` `<p>` etc

   ```
   <drug>
       <title>Paracetamol</title>
       <indications outputclass="indicationsAndDose">
           <title>Indications and dose</title>
           <body>
               <section outputclass="indicationAndDoseGroup">
                   <sectiondiv outputclass="therapeuticIndications">
                       <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 1</p>
                       <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 2</p>
                   </sectiondiv>
               </section>
           </body>
       </indications>
   </drug>
   ```

Comment: @zx485 FYI, here you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the sort of merge you want, because your requirements are quite vague! However, it produces the output from the input you provided:

```
declare variable $local:xml1 := document {
    <drug>
        <title>Paracetamol</title>
        <indications outputclass="indicationsAndDose">
            <title>Indications and dose</title>
            <body>
                <section outputclass="indicationAndDoseGroup">
                    <sectiondiv outputclass="therapeuticIndications">
                        <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 1</p>
                    </sectiondiv>
                </section>
            </body>
        </indications>
    </drug>
};
declare variable $local:xml2 := document {
    <drug>
        <title>Abacavir</title>
        <indications outputclass="indicationsAndDose">
            <title>Indications and dose</title>
            <body>
                <section outputclass="indicationAndDoseGroup">
                    <sectiondiv outputclass="therapeuticIndications">
                        <p outputclass="therapeuticIndication">Some indication 2</p>
                    </sectiondiv>
                </section>
            </body>
        </indications>
    </drug>
};

declare function local:merge($i1, $i2) {
    if (node-name($i1) eq node-name($i2)) then
        (
            (: When elements are the same and the value is different
               and they have no attributes they should be merged 
               e.g. "Paracetamol" and "Abacavir"
            :)
            if (empty(($i1/@*, $i2/@*))) then
                element {node-name($i1)} {
                    $i1/@*,
                    $i1/text(),
                    let $ii1 := $i1/node()[1]
                    let $ii2 := $i2/node()[1]
                    return
                        if (not(empty($ii1)) and not(empty($ii2))) then
                            local:merge($ii1, $ii2)
                        else()
                }

            (: When the elements have the same attribute then they
               should be merged value e.g. "Some indication 1"
            :)
            else if (fn:deep-equal($i1/@*, $i2/@*)) then
                (
                    element {node-name($i1)} {
                        $i1/@*,
                        $i1/text(),
                        let $ii1 := $i1/node()[1]
                        let $ii2 := $i2/node()[1]
                        return
                            if (not(empty($ii1)) and not(empty($ii2))) then
                                local:merge($ii1, $ii2)
                            else()
                    },
                    if (not(empty($i1/text())) and not(empty($i2/text()))) then
                        element {node-name($i2)} {
                            $i2/@*,
                            $i2/text()
                        }
                    else()
                )
            else (),
            let $ii1 := $i1/following-sibling::node()[1]
            let $ii2 := $i2/following-sibling::node()[1]
            return
                if (not(empty($ii1)) and not(empty($ii2))) then
                    local:merge($ii1, $ii2)
                else()
        )
    else()
};

local:merge($local:xml1/drug, $local:xml2/drug)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've added more detail to the acceptance criteria to make it more clearer. The solution must be dynamic in that I've noticed your solution is specifically looking for the `p` tag. The requirements could be applied to any number of different elements.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it dynamic as you requested

Comment: Wonderful, thank you I have accepted the answer! Can you please up vote my question as somebody feel it's not relevant which I think is just silly.

Comment: I think your question is very specific to solving your own problem rather than one that people can learn from, so for that reason I probably won't upvote it

Comment: I don't think that's the case at all. My problem isn't necessarily just "my problem" there could be others wanting to do something very similar. Isn't that the whole-point of SO? I have learned from "other people's problems" and very good SO questions have got many up votes where the problem is actually very specific to the questioner. Besides as far as I know SO policies don't expect formulating questions that aren't specific to solving ones own problems I think that's getting quite pedantic IMHO.